# Add parameter on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
        $(document).on("click", '#btn', function() {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var sub=document.getElementById("tables").rows.length;
                for(var i=0;i<sub;i++){
                    var doc=document.getElementById("checkbox"+i);
                    if(doc.checked!=false){
                        $("#tables>tr[id='i']").remove();
                    }
                }
            });
    });
});
```

help to add with parameter how to add variable tr[id='i']

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Can you elaborate?  (Edit: The other responses so far indicate that you're asking how to concatenate the value `i` into your string.  But you are *already doing exactly that* two lines earlier.  If that's the problem, why can't you just repeat what you already successfully did?)

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique in HTML, that is why your selector doesn't make any sense, `$("#tables>tr[id='"+i+"']")` should be the same as `$("#"+i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
$("#tables>tr[id='i']").remove();
```

with this

```
 $("#tables>tr[id='"+i+"']").remove();
```